# Ошибка NameError: name 'bike_data' is not defined при работе в терминале Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

При работе программы в терминале выдаёт ошибку NameError.
Сам код из учебника Саммерфилда.

Программа bikestock.py находится в папке,откуда и запустил терминал с указанием файла bikestock.py но уже при самом вызове bikestock он выдаёт NameError.

```
ususus@ususus-K53SJ:~/Рабочий стол/MyProjects/Python/Glava7$ python -i bikestock.py
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>> bike_file = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),"bikes.dat")
>>> if os.path.exists(bike_file): os.remove(bike_file)
... 
>>> bike_data=[]
>>> bike_data.append(('REFK2','Reflex Kalahari',5,200.97))
>>> bike_data.append(('REFT1','Reflex Tempus',4,200.97))
>>> bike_data.append(('UNISTOW','Universal Stowaway',1,203.00))
>>> bike_data.append(('REFONA','Reflex Out About',0,213.15))
>>> bike_data.append(('B4U16RS','Bicycles 16/6/RS',0,223.50))
>>> bike_data.append(('B4U20','Bicycles4U 20/6',9,223.50))
>>> bike_data.append(('B4U20MTB','Bicycles4U 20/6/MTB',5,223.50))
>>> bicycles = bikestock(bike_file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bikestock' is not defined
>>>
```

UPD:
Привожу полный код bikestock.py()

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding: utf8

import pickle
import os
import sys
import tempfile
import struct
import BinaryRecordFile

class Bike:    
    def __init__(self,identity,name,quantity,price):
        assert len(identity)>3, ("invalid bike identity '{0}';".format(identity))
        self.__identity = identity
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price

    @property
    def identify(self):
        "The bike's identity"
        return self._identity

    @property
    def name(self):
        "The bike's name"
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self,name):
        assert len(name),"bike name must not be empty"
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def quantity(self):
        "How many of this bike are in stock"
        return self.__quantity

    @quantity.setter
    def quantity(self,quantity):
        assert 0 <=quantity,"quantity must not be negative"
        self.__quantity=quantity

    @property
    def price(self):
        "The bike's price"
        return self.__price


    @price.setter
    def name(self,price):
        assert 0.0<=price,"price must not be negative"
        self.__price = price

    @property
    def value(self):
         "The value of these bikes in stock"
         return self.quantity * self.price

_BIKE_STRUCT = struct.Struct("<8s30sid")

def _bike_from_record(record):
       ID, NAME, QUANTITY, PRICE = range(4)
       parts = list(_BIKE_STRUCT.unpack(record))
       parts[ID] = parts[ID].decode("utf8").rstrip("\x00")
       parts[NAME] = parts[NAME].decode("utf8").rstrip("\x00")
       return Bike(*parts)

def _record_from_bike(bike):
       return _BIKE_STRUCT.pack(bike.identity.encode("utf8"),
                                bike.name.encode("utf8"),
                                bike.quantity,bike.price)

class BikeStock:
   def __init__(self,filename):
        self.__file = BinaryRecordFile.BinaryRecordFile(filename,_BIKE_STRUCT.size)
        self.__index_from_identity = {}
        for index in range(len(self.__file)):
            record = self.__file[index]
            if record is not None:
                bike = _bike_from_record(record)
                self.__index_from_identity[bike.identity] = index

#Соединяет и закрывает файл  
   def close(self):
       self._file.inplace_compact()
       self._file.close()

#Добавляет новый байк на запас
   def append(self,bike):
        index = len(self.__file)
        self.__file[index] = _record_from_bike(bike)
        self.__index_from_identity[bike.indentity] = index

#Удаляет запись запаса для указанного велосипеда
   def __delitem__(self,identity):
      index = self.__index_from_identity[identity]
      del self.__file[index]   
      del self.__index_from_identity[identity]
      for key,value in self.__index_from_identity.items():
          if value>index:
              self.__index_from_identity[key]=value-1


#Извлекает запись запаса для указанного велосипеда
   def __getitem__(self,identity):
       record = self.__file[self.__index_from_identity[identity]]
       return None if record is None else _bike_from_record(record)

   def __change_bike(self,identity,what,value):
       index = self.__index_from_identity[identity]
       record = self.__file[index]
       if record is None:
          return False
       bike = _bike_from_record(record)
       if what == "price" and value is not None and value >=0.0:
         bike.rpice = value
       elif what == "name" and value is not None:
         bike.name = Value
       else:
           return False
       self.__file[index] = _record_from_bike(bike)
       return True

   change_name = lambda self,identity,name:self.__change_bike(identity,"name",name)

   change_name.__doc__ = "Changes the bike's name"

   change_price = lambda self,identity,price: self.__change_bike(identity,"price",name)

   change_price.__doc__="Changes the bike's price"


   def __change_stock_(self,identity,amount):
       index  = self.__index_from_identity[identity]
       record = self.__file[index]
       if record is None:
          return False
       bike = _bike_from_record(record)
       bike.quantity +=amount
       self.__file[index] = _record_from_bike(bike)
       return True

   increase_stock = (lambda self,identity,amount:self.__change_stock(identity,amount))

   increase_stock.__doc__=("Increases the stock held for the"
                           "specified bike by the given amount")

   decrease_stock = (lambda self,identity,amount:self.__change_stock(identity,-amount))

   decrease_stock.__doc__=("Decreases the stock held for the"
                           "specified bike by the given amount")


   def __iter__(self):
       for index in range(len(self.__file)):
           record = self.__file[index]
           if record is not None:
               yield _bike_from_record(record)

if __name__=="__main__":
     import doctest
     doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Вы сделали import bikestock или from bikestock import bikestock?

Comment: Приведите тогда уже и содержимое файла bikestock.py

Comment: @nick_gabpe, теоретически тут импорт может быть и не нужен - первой строчкой автор вопроса запускает bikestock.py в интерактивном режиме. То есть сначала выполняется этот скрипт и все имена, которые в нём определены будут доступны и в последующих командах, вводимых в консоли. Но это только если имя bikestock было в этом скрипте объявлено.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы хотели `BikeStock(bike_file)` вместо `bikestock(bike_file)`. Просто по параметрам подходит.

Comment: @eigenein вы оказались правы. Как я потом понял, нужно добавлять название класса,который внутри программы и уже работать с ним в интерактивном режиме